# Checking distinct values on column level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have four columns coming from my query. My requirement is to check if the values of all the columns are different then only select the result.

I have written this query and it is working fine. But I was just wondering if there is any better or shortcut way to achieve this

```
select FO, AFO, CO, ACO from mytable 
where 
(fo<>afo or (fo is null or afo is null))
and 
(fo<>co or (fo is null or co is null))
and 
(fo<>aco or (fo is null or aco is null))
and 
(afo<>co or (afo is null or co is null)) 
and 
(afo<>aco or (afo is null or aco is null))
and 
(co<>aco or (co is null or aco is null))
```

Comment: Can you supply a set of example data, your description of the expected result is a bit confusing.

Comment: @PawanNogariya can you please upload some sample data and output

Comment: In terms of a shortcut (and assuming you columns are of type varchar)
    (fo<>afo or (fo is null or afo is null))
can be written as

    COALESCE(fo, 'fo') <> COALESCE(afo, 'afo')

Comment: @DimiTakis that's not a good idea. This will force a full table scan even if there are indexes on the columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh well, disagreeing on that - the query plans are identical for both - just try at your side and you will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you seem to want the four values to be different or `NULL`.  A different method uses `apply`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t cross apply
     (select count(*)
      from (values (t.afo), (t.fo), (t.co), (t.aco)
           ) v(val)
      where val is not null
      having count(*) = count(distinct val)
     ) x;
```

This removes the `NULL` values and then checks that the remaining ones are all distinct.